# How to connect to Ms Sql Server with ActiveDirectoryIntegrated from JVM on windows

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I read the whole documentation on MS site but didn't find the answer on this question. Can anybody share jdbc url for this task?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I asked about ActiveDirectoryIntegrated. The other question about windows authentication mode

Comment: It's the same thing. [Check the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlauthenticationmethod?view=netframework-4.8) `Use Active Directory Integrated to connect to a SQL Database using integrated Windows authentication.`. This means that the connection will connect to the database as the account executiont the application. If you want to connect to a server on a different machine, the application must run under a domain account. This removes the need for specifying and storing passwords

Comment: If you use a *local* account on the other hand, the server has no idea who that account is. What does your connection string look like? Is it a local or domain account?

Comment: I've only been using it for 23 years to connect to both local and remote SQL Server databases (and file shares, and write web applications), so I don't think so. You should explain what your actual problem is. If you use a *local* account, you can't connect to a remote machine simply because your account has no meaning for that other machine - in fact, the connection will be made using the computer's account. If you use a domain account though, the remote server can identify it and validate its permissions with the domain controller. If you use `Local Service` or `Local System`, it's local

Comment: I could get into how local vs domain differ, which well-known accounts are used for remote service access etc. but in *your* case it doesn't really matter. It should just work, no username/password required. So, if you have a problem, explain it in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you please explain or share the documentations which show me what happen when I set `integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NativeAuthentication` and when I set `authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated` in my jdbc string